# Facebook Share Products

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

Good day,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24

According to the above post, the publish_actions permission is deprecated, and that one should use the Sharing products to enable an app to post to facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing

The sharing products above allow one to share a video, or a picture, or a link to the facebook feed. However, I just want to post text. I don't think there's any documentation on how to do that.

Is it not allowed?

Kind regards,

Jon

Comment: Correct that is not allowed according to Facebook Platform Policy.

Comment: I was asked to figure it out because the product dev has a hanx writer app on ios. This app is able to post to the fb feed. What do I explain? The test app, being made in 2018, is subject to new FB Platform Policies that do not allow that?

Comment: prefilling the message was never allowed, that´s nothing new.

Comment: Since I'm on android, I'll have go to the office and borrow the office iphone and install the app on it, to see it's behavior. If that's the case, do I delete this question and ask a new one? I don't think it should be on stack overflow because it's more of a "How do I convince the another (non tech) person" type of question.

Comment: Tell the person to read 2.3 in https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ . And it also doesn't really matter what the policy say anymore. Because the API doesn't allow it anymore. So it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not allowed anymore by the FB share products.